# ORDER BY priority with groups?

Tags: mysql, group-by

An example table:

```
NAME, PRIORITY, SORT
TEST1, 0, 11:10
TEST2, 1, 11:15
TEST3, 0, 11:20
TEST4, 1, 11:30
```

I would like to make the following priority listing with ordering to `priority`:

```
TEST2 (first submitted with priority)
TEST1
TEST3
TEST4
```

How to do that? I've tried with GROUP BY and so, but not succeed!

Comment: So you want the first row to be the earliest with priority 1 and the rest in order of time?

Comment: i dont get your criteria TEST4 has also got PRIORITY but comes after TEST1?

Comment: @ChetterHummin Correct!

Comment: If you are ordering by priority, the correct order should be TEST2, TEST4, TEST1 , TEST3

Comment: That's the point! I'm not ordering my priority! The first row has to be the first one with priority (depends on time) after that all the rows are ordered by time

Comment: If you want to put it in custom order you need to use CASE.

Comment: @Killrawr: No, then you'd get TEST1, TEST3, TEST2, TEST4 returned in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this.

```
  SELECT NAME 
    FROM table
   WHERE PRIORITY = 1
ORDER BY TIME ASC
   LIMIT 1
UNION 
  SELECT NAME 
    FROM table
ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

that should gave

```
TEST2 (first submitted with priority) TEST1 TEST3 TEST4
```

edit forgot priority

Comment: The second query doesn't exclude the row from the first so it'll be returned twice even. Also, does unioning two queries respect their individual orderings? (It's not something I've ever tried to do.)

Comment: I'm not sure. There should be a WHERE `priority` added!

Comment: @Patashu In MYSQL, UNION removes duplicates by default

Comment: @Patashu Union should remove duplicates because MySQL uses same Index Merge while calling table AFAIK. If there will be a problem we can add id to the Query.

Comment: @SKylineman . . . just because it *looks* like it is working does not mean that it really does work.  The ordering is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/30/sql-server-union-all-and-order-by-how-to-order-table-separately-while-using-union-all/ you cannot have two separate orders in opposite sides of a union. But what you can do is add a new column and sort by that column.

The website suggests something like (though this is for sql server, I don't know if mysql uses the same syntax)

```
Select name, priority, sort, '1' OrderKey from table where priority = 1 and sort <= (select min(t3.sort) from table t3 where t3.priority = 1)
union
select name, priority, sort, '2' OrderKey from table
order by OrderKey, time asc
```

Again, this would work for sql server but not sure if it works for mysql.

edit: fixed query (hopefully...)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `name_priority_sort` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `name_priority_sort` (`id`, `name`, `priority`, `sort`)
VALUES
    (1,'Test1',0,'11:10:00'),
    (2,'Test2',1,'11:15:00'),
    (3,'Test3',0,'11:20:00'),
    (4,'Test4',1,'11:30:00');

select `name`, priority, sort from (
    select 1 `set`, `name`, priority, min(sort) sort from `name_priority_sort` where priority = 1
    union all
    select 2 `set`, `name`, priority, sort from `name_priority_sort` where `name` not in (
        select `name` from (
            select `name`, priority, min(sort) sort from `name_priority_sort` where priority = 1
        ) first_set
    ) 
) sets
order by `set`, sort

-- results

name    priority    sort
Test2   1   11:15:00
Test1   0   11:10:00
Test3   0   11:20:00
Test4   1   11:30:00
```